# Unity3d & Unity WebPlayer Can't get these working

Tags: unity, wine, games

I'm trying to get Unity3d work on Ubuntu 14.04 and also Unity Webplayer.

As a young Game developer, its very important I have Unity (Game Engine) so I can continue to make games. I tried Installing .exe Using Wine, which worked but when I open Unity afterwards it basically say error unable to open.

Unity Web player I use this all the time can someone help me to get this on Chromiun.
I tried using pipelight, but nothing: http://fenglee.com/game/aog/ anyone can get this game to run?

Answer (score 0):

Chromium dropped support for NPAPI plugins on Linux and therefore does not work with Pipelight any more, see http://pipelight.net/cms/chrome-chromium.html for more information. I would suggest using any other browser supporting NPAPI plugins like Firefox, Midori, uzbl, etc.